# How to create an async function in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

Is there a way in Clojurescript create an async function or a macro wrap a function into a Promise to simulate it?
My current use-case is to replace the following function that takes a callback by its async version - btw this is for an [AWS lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html).

```js
// Old style
function(args, callback) {
  // Use callback(e) for errors
  // Use callback(null, value) for the result
}

// New style
async function(args) {
  return value; // success path
  throw new Error(); // error path
}
```

Given that this is Clojurescript, using `await` is not the question. And I know this can simply return a Promise to comply with the `async` requirement.
So it resolves to some sugar code to create the Promise, catch all errors for me and calling resolve on the happy path or reject otherwise.

Browsing through [`clojure.core.async`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/tree/master/src/main/clojure/cljs/core/async) and docs -including the [clojurescript reference](https://clojurescript.org/guides/promise-interop), I  haven't found anything.

Answer (score 3):

Node 8 and newer ship with [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) that does what you want:

> Takes a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e. taking a (err, value) => ... callback as the last argument, and returns a version that returns promises.

**EDIT**: I spent a bit writing a macro that does `promisify` and I'm safisfied with the result. Note that the macro needs to be saved in a CLJC file:

```clj
;; macros.cljc ;;;;;;;;;;
(ns server.macros)

(defmacro promisify [method obj params]
  `(js/Promise.
    (fn [resolve# reject#]
      (~method ~obj ~params
       (fn [err# result#]
         (if err#
           (reject# err#)
           (resolve# result#)))))))

;; main.cljs ;;;;;;;;;;
(ns server.main
  (:require-macros [server.macros :refer [promisify]])
  (:require ["aws-sdk" :as aws]))

(defn main! []
  (println "App loaded...")
  (let [creds (aws/SharedIniFileCredentials. #js {:profile "example-profile"})
        _     (set! (.-credentials aws/config) creds)
        s3    (aws/S3.)]
    (-> (promisify .listBuckets s3 #js {})
        (.then #(println "DATA:" %))
        (.catch #(println "ERROR:" %)))))
```

and the output is the same as before:

```
$ node target/main.js

App loaded...
DATA: #js {:Buckets #js [#js {:Name demo-test-bucket, :CreationDate #inst "2019-05-05T17:32:17.000-00:00"} #js {:Name subdomain.mydomain.com, :CreationDate #inst "2019-06-19T04:16:10.000-00:00"}], :Owner #js {:DisplayName username, :ID 9f7947b2d509e2338357d93e74f2f88a7528319ab3609b8d3b5be6b3a872dd2c}}
```

The macro is basically a Clojure version of [this code](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/promise#converting-a-callback-style-function-to-return-a-promise).

**EDIT 2**: There's also [this library](https://github.com/jamesmacaulay/cljs-promises) that could be interesting if you really want to use core.async too.

Comment: Many thanks. I must say I still hope for a solution in clojure.core.async, as it is referenced as THE solution for interop with JS in terms of Promise. If nothing comes, I'll mark this as  the solution.

Comment: Many thanks for the updated answer but I realized that this is not the right answer. By converting to an async method, I want to not have to care about the `callback` argument, while `promisify` only converts an existing function requiring the callback into a promise. This function to convert is me and it still has to use the callback but the end user - AWS in my case - won't. I'll look at cljs-promises